# IDE or Terminal in box empty

Tags: nitrousio

I have been playing around with Meteor development using Nitrous.IO Node.JS box.

Since a few days ago when I access either the IDE or Terminal of the box, the IDE or the Terminal that is opened is empty (nothing in console, files tree) and not responding.
In the IDE it seems to be stuck on 'connecting...'.

I have tried to restart and shutdown/start the box, but no luck.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nitrous is an early service, and as of this time seems (in my experience, to still be buggy).  Best to confirm service issues with them first.